# Classic ASP/ADO/SQL - Form Submitting to DB on page load, not on submit

Tags: database, forms, asp-classic, ado

I'm trying to learn how to interact with a database with ADO using VBScript.  I've got my connection and sql sorted.

My concern is that on load of the browser window the form is submitting empty rows to the database without actually being submitted.  Have done a bit of searching around and can't find a tangible answer to this.

Any help would be appreciated.  Code below.  Thanks.

```
<%@Language="vbscript" codepage="65001"%>
<% 
Dim objConn, connStr, strSql 
Dim name, pass, addBtn
  connStr = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=userDataColl;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
  name = Request.Form("username")
  pass = Request.Form("password")
  addBtn = Request.Form("addBtn") ' gave the submit button a name attribute and grabbed it on server code.  
  removeBtn = Request.Form("removeBtn")

Function insertUser()
If addBtn <> "" Then ' new logic here to ensure that the button has actually been pressed before carrying out the ADO operations.  
    strSql = "INSERT INTO dbo.userLogins (userName, passW) VALUES (" & "'" & name & "', " & "'" & pass & "'" & ")"
    
    Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
      objConn.Open(connstr)
      objConn.Execute strSql, , adCmdText
      objConn.Close 
    Set objConn = Nothing
  End If ' end of new logic encapsulation.  
End Function

Function deleteUser()
If removeBtn <> "" Then  
  strSql = "DELETE FROM dbo.userLogins WHERE userName =" & "'" & name & "'"

  Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConn.Open(connstr)
    objConn.Execute strsql, , adCmdText
    objConn.Close
    Set objConn = Nothing
End If 
End Function
%>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>DataBase Queries</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="dbQueries.asp">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Add Data</td>
    <td><input name="username"></td>
    <td><input name="password"></td>
    <td><input name = "addBtn" type = "Submit" value = "Add User" onsubmit="<%=insertUser%>"></td>
    <td><input name ="removeBtn" type="Submit" value = "Remove User" onsubmit="<%=deleteUser%>"></td>
  </tr>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As you identified in your answer, this is a duplicate of [Stop ASP script auto-running on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505098/stop-asp-script-auto-running-on-page-load). Given that, I'm voting to close this question so that it will be redirected to that more-established thread.

Comment: Sad times.  Downvoted despite self admining my post xD  ah well.

Comment: I'm sorry to see that. I think the question was fine. We obviously want to focus attention on canonical examples of questions, but I wouldn't have downvoted the question.

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer.  Duplicate of [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505098/stop-asp-script-auto-running-on-page-load)

Added logic to ensure the submit button was actually pressed.  Silly of me, but learning's learning.
Closed.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include the logic that you added? Without it, this answer relies primarily on the linked page.

Comment: You may also find it useful to split up the page where you post to with the page on the form, and the post page only contain your logic to save the form. 

In the long run, it makes it easier to manage, IMO, even though you end up with more pages.

Comment: Will do so now.  Thanks guys.  And thanks for the further advice on it too, @larrybud.  I appreciate it.